# Is it possible to disable/override a ScriptResourceMapping requirement?

Tags: unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-4.5

I upgraded a WebForms project to .net 4.5, and received this error:

> WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping
>   for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named
>   jquery(case-sensitive).

I'd like to enable UnobtrusiveValidation, but I'm using Combres for Javascript resources, so I don't want the ScriptManager to try to download it again. Is it possible to tell the ScriptManager to just trust me that it will be loaded? In other words, I want to add a mapping for "jquery" that does nothing. It's apparently not possible to add a ScriptResourceDefinition with a name but no paths. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell the answer is no.

This question has been asked on http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735928/in-asp-net-web-application-visual-basic-the-requiredfieldvalidator-doest-work and on http://forums.asp.net/t/1850831.aspx/1 with no answers.

As a quick and nasty workaround to this problem I have added an empty file called DummyJQuery.js into the solution put the code below into application_start:

```
 Dim jQuery As New ScriptResourceDefinition()
 jQuery.Path = "~/js/DummyJQuery.js"
 jQuery.DebugPath = "~/js/DummyJQuery.js"
 ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/465613/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear and I've edited it. That page suggests that I add a jquery reference to the ScriptManager, but I don't want it to download another copy of jQuery - I already load it as part of my Combres Resource.

Comment: Have you already tried this solution? I would've presumed it just added a reference to JQuery so the script manager knew about it (i.e. not download multiple copies).

Comment: I have, it adds script tags for the cdn version, a check for whether it's loaded, and for the local version if that fails. Honestly, if it would also do a check for jQuery before doing the *CDN* version, it'd be fine.